# Object's matrix_parent_inverse Value After Parent's Origin Change

Tags: python, scripting, matrix

If the `matrix_parent_inverse` of an object **o** that's parented to another object **p** is initially **M1**, and if it becomes **M2** after the origin of **p** is shifted by Vector **v**, what is the relationship between **M1** and **M2**?

In other words, given **v** and **M1** is it possible to find **M2**?

I am trying to shift the origin of an object through script. But after change of origin the child objects all move in seemingly random directions. I want the child object to retain their position after the origin change of the parent.